# Joda time changes UTC offset on date adjustment

Tags: java, jodatime

This code:

```
DateTime n1 = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(n1);
DateTime n2 = n1.withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0);
System.out.println(n2);
```

results in output:

```
2014-11-02T15:03:16.387-06:00
2014-11-02T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

Why did the offset from UTC change based on this assignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [daylight savings switched](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york) in the night of 2 November 2014:

- 2 November 2014, 15:03:16 in the timezone America/Chicago was in wintertime (UTC - 6 hours)
- 2 November 2014, 00:00:00 in the timezone America/Chicago was in summertime (UTC - 5 hours)

Comment: @JamesJ Please accept a correct answer to mark this question as resolved. Click the big empty checkmark icon found beneath the Up and Down triangle buttons.